# Lemma on number of Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ and index of $P$ in its normaliser correct?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

In [this article](https://doi.org/10.2307/2974771) I found the following lemma:

> Let $p$ be prime and $G$ be a transitive subgroup of $S_p$, and suppose $|\textrm{Syl}_p(G)|>1$. Then $|N_G(P):P|>1$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-group and $N_G(P)$ is the normaliser of $P$ in $G$.

Why doesn't the following argument disprove it?

We can assume that $G$ is not the cyclic group with $p$ elements (otherwise $G=P$ and there is nothing to prove) but because $G$ is transitive its order is divisible by $p$. Therefore, the contraposition of the claim is: if $|N_G(P):P|=1$ then $|\textrm{Syl}_p(G)|=1$. But the condition means that $P$ is not normal because if it were normal then $N_G(P)=G\neq P$. But if $P$ is not normal then there must be more than 1 Sylow $p$-group and $|\textrm{Syl}_p(G)|>1$ as a Sylow $p$-group is unique if and only if it is normal.

The article is "An Elementary Proof of the Simplicity of the Mathieu Groups $M_{11}$ and $M_{23}$" by Robin Chapman, 1995.

Comment: Doesn't your argument just show that if $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$, and its Sylow $p$-subgroup is self-normalizing, then $G$ is cyclic of order $p$? The assumption you are making that is leading you to a contradiction is that "$G$ is not the cyclic group with $p$ elements".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm still confused. Let me drop the assumption that $G$ is not $C_p$. Then there are two cases. 1) $G=C_p$. In that case the condition of the original lemma doesn't hold as $G$ itself is its only Sylow $p$-subgroup. 2) $G\neq C_p$. Now I'm back in for my argument.

Comment: Yes, you are confused. If $G=C_p$, then the original lemma *holds* in the sense that its premise is false, so the implication it contains is true; that is, the lemma is true. *Your* version is true, because in that case $G=P=N_G(P)$, and you *do* have that $[N_G(P):P]=1$ implies $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)|=1$. And your argument shows that $G\neq C_p$ is impossible. That’s all you are doing.

Comment: What you proved, like Jack said, is that the only transitive subgroup of $S_p$ with a self-normalizing Sylow $p$-subgroup is $C_p$. You showed any other possibility leads to a contradiction. I don’t know why you are so resistant to it. The paper isn’t seeking to find the best description possible of these groups: it is a short note and it only needs to conclude this for its purpose. The Lemma could have been stated as “If $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ with a self-normalizing Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $G\cong C_p$,” but then he would need to invoke the contrapositive for its purpose.,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Maybe the fog is lifting. You're saying that the lemma does nothing more than proving that we are dealing with $C_p$ in that situation. (I haven't read on yet since I thought it wouldn't make sense until I resolved my issues with the lemma.) I had the impression it tried to prove something about a situation I deemed to be impossible and that this something would be crucial for the further argument. Therefore, I felt to be in a trap of ex falso quodlibet. Thanks for taking care of my thick-wittedness. (I guess. )

Comment: Your version of the lemma shows that if a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ has a self-normalizing $p$-Sylow, then the group is cyclic of order $p$ and the Sylow is normal.  The lemma as stated in the note says that if you have a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ and its $p$-Sylow are not normal, then they is not self-normalizing. He doesn’t describe that the only exception to “Sylows are not self-normalizing” are the cyclic subgroups of order $p$ because he doesn’t need that extra information.

Answer (score 3):

The only transitive group $G$ of prime degree $p$ with $N_G(P)=P$ for $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup is $G=P$ itself. So your proof doesn't contradict the lemma, it just broadens its applicability.

Here is the adjustment to the proof in the paper:

> *Proof:* Suppose $G$ is a (faithful) transitive group on $p$ points and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $N=N_G(P)$. Then $|G| = |P|[N:P][G:N]$. Note $|P|=p$. Set $m=[G:N]$ and $r=[N:P]$. Then $|G| = prm$. Since intersections of distinct conjugates of $P$ intersect in the identity, we get $m(p-1)$ elements of order $p$. Consider a point stabilizer $H$. It has index $p$, and so has no elements of order $p$. In other words, $|H|=rm$ and $H\cap P = 1$.
>
> Suppose $r=1$. Then $m(p-1) = mrp-m = |G|-m$ elements have order $p$, and only $m$ elements have other orders. Thus there are only $m$ possible elements left in $G$ to make up $H$. Since $|H|=rm=m$, that means $H$ is exactly those $m$ elements. However, the same is true for all the point stabilizers, $H^g$, so that those exact same elements are used in every $H^g$. Said more simply, $H=H^g$ for all $g$ and $H$ is normal.
>
> A faithful transitive group is exactly one in which $\bigcap\limits_{g\in G} H^g = 1$, but this group has $\bigcap\limits_{g\in G} H^g = \bigcap\limits_{g\in G} H = H$. We conclude that $H=1$ and the group is regular. Since $|H|=rm=1$ we get $m=1$ as well, and $|G|=prm=p$ so that $G=P$.☐

The paper uses slightly different language, but hopefully both are clear. Another way to finish is a classic exercise: somewhere in the middle we have shown $G=H \cup P$, but that can only happen if $G=H$ (no) or $G=P$, yes.

Comment: Right... the contradiction arises from assuming $G$ is not cyclic of order $p$.

Comment: yes exactly. I saw your comment after I hit submit :-)

Comment: Hm, I (and the paper) didn't say that G was of prime degree. In fact, what do we want to prove in case of $|G|=p$? In that case there is just one Sylow $p$-subgroup ($G$ itself) and the condition of the lemma doesn't hold. Also see my answer to Arturo's comment. You both say my contradiction is to assume $G\neq C_p$. But why mustn't I? There is nothing to it if $G=C_p$.

Comment: @diffset: “prime degree” means “contains in $S_p$ for some prime $p$”. The degree is the number of elements it is acting on.